# STM32WL ADC during STOP modes impossible?

Tags: stm32, low-power

I want to sample a signal with the ADC for a certain time (one-shot) and keep the CPU in the lowest power mode possible.
ADC is triggered by TIM1 and DMA is set up.

When using SLEEP mode, HAL_COMP_TriggerCallback gets triggered as expected.
When using STOP modes, is not anymore.

I tried explicitly enabling TIM1 and ADC clocks before going to STOP, which had no effect.

In [AN5568](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an5568-ultralowpower-features-of-stm32wl-series-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf) it says:

> The STM32WL devices implement three Stop modes (Stop 0 , Stop 1, Stop 2), with full SRAM and peripheral
> retention, and a wakeup capabilities. In these Stop modes, all the high-speed oscillators (HSE, MSI, HSI) are
> stopped, while the active low‑speed oscillators (LSE and/or LSI) are kept active. The peripherals are set to active
> using the HSI clock when needed, to wake up the device on a specific event

Does this mean, it is impossible to have the ADC running in STOP modes on an STM32WL?
Additionally, is it possible on other series like STM32L4, as they seem to implement ADC deep sleep modes?